# counting characters in a file i cant find whats wrong

Tags: c

Why wont this function count the characters in the text?I open the file in the main function which includes countchars.also the file is open from a function before countchars but i close it at the end of countchars.And why does fscanf without !=EOF reads only the last letter-word?

```
void countchars(FILE *p){
        char ch;
        int countc=0;
        for(;(fscanf(p,"%c",&ch)!=EOF);countc++);
        printf("%d",countc);
```

REST OF THE CODE:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int getchoice(void);
void inserttextfromfile();
void printtextdata(FILE *);
void countwords(FILE *);
void calculatetextstatistics();
void countchars(FILE *);
int main(){ 
    int a;
    while((a=getchoice())){
      switch (a){
            case 1:
                  break;
            case 2:    ;
                  break;
            case 3:    ;
                  break;
            case 4:    ;
                  break;
            case 5:calculatetextstatistics() ;
                  break;
            case 6:    ;
                  break;
            default: break;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
int getchoice(){
    int a;
    scanf("%d",&a);
    return a;
}

void calculatetextstatistics(){
    FILE *p;
    p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
    countwords(p);
    countchars(p);
    fclose(p);
}
void countwords(FILE *p){
    int countw=0;
    char wordholder[10]=" ";
    char wordlist[60][10];
    for (;(fscanf(p,"%s",wordholder))!= EOF;countw++);
    printf("%d\n",countw);
    return;
}
void countchars(FILE *p){
    char ch;

    int countc=0;
    for(;(fscanf(p,"%c",&ch)!=EOF);countw++);
    printf("%d",countw);

}
```

Comment: Fsanf return number of read arguments

Comment: why `c++` tag ?

Comment: Since you're only scanning a single character at a time, is there a reason you're using `fscanf` instead of e.g. `fgetc`?

Comment: can only use fscanf.i also cant print ch if i try printf("%c",ch).isnt the character that fscanf read saved in ch?

Comment: `fscanf()` doesn't return `EOF` -- `fgetc()` indeed would.

Comment: Using `printf("%c", ch)` would be more nearly correct than `printf(%c,&ch)` outlined in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50066269/counting-characters-in-a-file-i-cant-find-whats-wrong#comment87149262_50066269).

Comment: "*can only use fscanf*" <-- **why?**

Comment: @FelixPalmen: Homework requirement!  95% confident.

Comment: can someone tell me how to correct this code?and why isnt it working as intented?

Comment: If your function doesn't open the file, it shouldn't close it either.  You should show the remainder of the function — the closing brace is missing.  We also need to see where it is called.  You've not showed how you call the code.  Please read about how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]) so that we can see what you're doing.  The problem may not be in the function you show.

Comment: So the homework is to accomplish the task in the most stupid (sorry) way one could imagine? Wow... still, solution should be simple, check for `==1` instead of `!=EOF`.

Comment: so the function is 100% correct?

Comment: @FelixPalmen: `fscanf()` does return EOF on EOF; it can also 1 for the given code.  In general, it could also return 0, but the `%c` format accepts any character so it won't return 0 under any circumstances I can think of.

Comment: Hint: Old video rental days had the adage: ["Be kind: rewind"](https://www.wholeheartedmen.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/rewind-590x295.jpg).

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're correct :o I was pretty sure it would just be "*a value < 0*" -- that's what you get writing about functions you normally avoid ;)

Comment: i knew it should be !=EOF

Answer (score 3):

Your approach for reading the file contents is quite inefficient but should work, unless the stream pointer `p` has an invalid value such as `NULL`.

The classic code for this purpose is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void countchars(FILE *fp) {
    int ch;
    int countc = 0;
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF)
        countc++;
    printf("%d\n", countc);
}
```

Your function fails because the stream has already been read up to the end of file. You can reset the file stream to the start of file with `rewind(fp);` or `fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);` but not all streams can be rewound this way.  For example reading from the console cannot be restarted.

Your function to count words is broken: if any word in the file is longer than 9 bytes, you have undefined behavior. You should instead read one character at a time and count the number of transitions from space to non-space characters:

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void countwords(FILE *fp) {
    int countw = 0;
    int c, lastc = '\n';

    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {
        countw += isspace(lastc) && !isspace(c);
        lastc = c;
    }
    printf("%d\n", countw);
}
```

If you insist on using `fscanf()`, here is an alternative:

```
void countwords(FILE *fp) {
    int countw = 0;
    char c, lastc = '\n';

    while (fscanf(fp, "%c", &c) == 1) {
        countw += isspace((unsigned char)lastc) && !isspace((unsigned char)c);
        lastc = c;
    }
    printf("%d\n", countw);
}
```

Comment: "is quite inefficient" --> perhaps.  Yet an optimizing compiler may emit similar efficient code for `fscanf(p,"%c",&ch)!=EOF` as `(c = getc(fp)) != EOF`.  I've been surprised by efficient `fprintf()` code.  OTOH I do find `(c = getc(fp)) != EOF)` an easy idiom to follow.

Comment: @JonBadiali: absolutely! answer updated. Come to think of it, it should be `fp` everywhere, short for *file pointer*.

Answer (score 3):

#### When the real code is shown

You have:

```
FILE *p;
p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
countwords(p);
countchars(p);
fclose(p);
```

Since `countwords()` reads to EOF, `countchars()` immediately gets EOF.  Use:

```
FILE *p;
p=fopen("mytext.txt","rt");
countwords(p);
rewind(p);
countchars(p);
fclose(p);
```

This rewinds the file stream to the start of the file after `countwords()` has reached EOF so that `countchars()` can reread the file.  Note that this works only on regular disk files; it would not work on pipes, terminals, sockets because you can't seek on those.  There are fairly simple ways to make a single pass over the data to count the characters and words without needing to reread the data.  Those are beyond the immediate scope of this question, though.

This also demonstrates perfectly the importance of an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).  It makes it trivial to solve your problem — without the MCVE, there isn't a problem to solve.

Note that the code about `getchoice()` and the big switch in `main()` is not material to an MCVE.  I also had to fix the code in the example to get it to compile.

Here's a minimized version of your code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void countwords(FILE *);
void calculatetextstatistics(void);
void countchars(FILE *);

int main(void)
{
    calculatetextstatistics();

    return 0;
}

void calculatetextstatistics(void)
{
    FILE *p = fopen("mytext.txt", "rt");
    countwords(p);
    rewind(p);
    countchars(p);
    fclose(p);
}

void countwords(FILE *p)
{
    int countw = 0;
    char wordholder[80] = " ";
    for ( ; (fscanf(p, "%s", wordholder)) != EOF; countw++)
        ;
    printf("%d\n", countw);
}

void countchars(FILE *p)
{
    char ch;
    int countc = 0;

    for ( ; (fscanf(p, "%c", &ch) != EOF); countc++)
        ;
    printf("%d\n", countc);
}
```

When I link its source to `mytext.txt`, it gives the output `83 695`, and `wc -wc` also gives the same answer.

#### First pass

Given an MCVE like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static void countchars(FILE *p)
{
    char ch;
    int countc = 0;
    for ( ; (fscanf(p, "%c", &ch) != EOF); countc++)
        ;
    printf("%d", countc);
    putchar('\n');
}

int main(void)
{
    countchars(stdin);
    return 0;
}
```

and compiling it to a program `cc17`, and running it on its own source:

```
$ gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Werror cc17.c -o cc17 
$ ./cc17 < cc17.c
254
$
```

This shows that the code you show 'works' — the problem is in the code you don't show.

Comment: do i need another headerfile for rewind?i call rewind but still the same

Comment: The [`rewind()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/rewind.html) function is part of Standard C and is declared in `<stdio.h>`.  I'll poke at your code.  Please note that an MCVE would not include all the `getchoice()` code; the `main()` would simply call the `calculatetextstatistics()` function.

Comment: Note that your code shows: `void countchars(FILE *p){
    char ch;

    int countc=0;
    for(;(fscanf(p,"%c",&ch)!=EOF);countw++);
    printf("%d",countw);

}` — but that won't compile because `countw` is not declared (it should be `countc`).

Comment: u pointed that it remains at EOF after the first fopen and now its fixed.i know its waste of time and for the forum members but thank you.just need people to give direct answers on the code as it is and not using other functions and from me to show full code.